# HashSet not removing existing element

Tags: java, hash, set, equals

I have a class Output which basically contains a BitSet with overides on hashCode and equals. Then I have a HashSet of Outputs and I do the following operations :

```
Set<Output> outputs = new HashSet<>();
Output o1 = new Output();
o1.flip(3);
Output o2 = new Output();
o2.flip(1);
o2.flip(3);
outputs.add(o1);
outputs.add(o2);
```

If I do a print(outputs) I get

```
[Output@5a1, Output@5a3]
```

Now if I do

`o2.flip(1);`

I get

```
[Output@5a3, Output@5a3]
```

which of course, is the normal behavior of a Set, since the Set can't be aware that the hashcode of an element has changed.

If I now do

```
outputs.remove(o1);
```

I get

```
[Output@5a3]
```

**Perfect!**

But if I do it again

```
outputs.remove(o1); //or outputs.remove(o2);
```

it returns `false` and I still have `[Output@5a3]`

And this is strange since if I do

```
outputs.contains(o1) -> false
```

which may explain the remove behavior, altough I don't understand why it returns false since if I do

```
    for(Output o : outputs) {
        System.out.println(o.equals(o1));
    }
```

It outputs `true`.

Any ideas why this happens?

The complete code:

```
class Output {
    BitSet values;

    public Output() {
        values = new BitSet(4);
    }

    public void flip(int index) {
        values.flip(index);
    }

    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 3;
        hash = 67 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.values);
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (!(obj instanceof Output)) {
            return false;
        }
        Output other = (Output) obj;
        return this.values.equals(other.values);
    }
}
public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Set<Output> outputs = new HashSet<>();
        Output o1 = new Output();
        o1.flip(3);
        Output o2 = new Output();
        o2.flip(1);
        o2.flip(3);
        outputs.add(o1);
        outputs.add(o2);
        System.out.println(outputs);
        o2.flip(1);
        System.out.println(outputs);
        outputs.remove(o1);
        System.out.println(outputs);
        outputs.remove(o1);
        System.out.println(outputs);
        for (Output o : outputs) {
            System.out.println(o.equals(o1));
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
[Output@5a1, Output@5a3]
[Output@5a3, Output@5a3]
[Output@5a3]
[Output@5a3]
true
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you mutate an element of a `HashSet` (or a key in a `HashMap`), the `hashCode` of that element may change (and in your example, the `hashCode` depends on the `hashCode` of the `BitSet` member, which you changed).

However, the `HashSet` is not aware of that change, and therefore doesn't move the element to the bin corresponding with the new `hashCode`.

Therefore, when you search for that element, the search is performed using the new `hashCode` (`HashSet` search always begins with the `hashCode` - only after finding the bin that contains all the elements having that `hashCode`, `equals()` is used to find the right element), and it fails, since the element is still located in the bin matching the original `hashCode`.

That's the reason it is a bad idea to mutate elements of a `HashSet`.

Comment: *"That's the reason it is a bad idea to mutate elements of a HashSet."* at least you should exclude the properties which may be mutated from hascode calculation...